# Issues facing with selenium webdirver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below code is part of my application. I am capturing the time as start before clicking and after that waiting for the sso_logout button to appear for 20 seconds and then capturing the end time .

My query is in any case the end-start time should not be more than 20 second. AM i correct ?

```
try{
            System.out.println("First");
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signin_google_button']/div[2]"));
            element.click();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            System.out.println("Second");
            element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#Email"));
            element.sendKeys(account);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            element = driver.findElement(By.id("next"));
            element.click();

            element = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
            element.sendKeys(password);
            element = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));

            countDownLatch.countDown();
            countDownLatch.await();

            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            element.click();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            WebElement sso_logout = (new WebDriverWait(driver,20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sso_logout")));
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Do you have an error or do you just want yes/no answer?

Comment: As later in the code i am capturing the (end-start) time for different threads .But as per my understanding it should wait for only 20 seconds for sso_logout to appear otherwise move ahead. But sometimes i will get (end-start) value more than 20 seconds

Comment: Can you please tell how come end-start value be greater than 20?

Comment: your wait time should be in Milliseconds not in seconds.

Comment: After converting time in millisecond, you are getting different as webdriver also take few second to wait for page load.

Comment: @SadikAli you mean the time 20 that i have given is in milisecond? My function is as above .I updated the question

Comment: 20 time is in second, not in milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, even you get more than 20 seconds as execution time, it should not be much. Since `element.click()` method is in between `start` and `end` variables, it may also take to identify the element and click on the link.

The following code should give the 20 second execution time (+/- 1 second):

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
WebElement sso_logout = (new WebDriverWait(driver,20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sso_logout")));
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Yes that will be fine for me . But for me sometimes it is coming like 40 seconds .I have some 20 threads and for all threads i need to capture the start and end time . I have updated my query mentioning the full function .

Comment: `element.click()` will make selenium wait for default wait time `60` seconds or user-defined wait time until the element is found and a click() action is performed. so `40` seconds is in range. After removing `element.click()` I will expect it will wait for `20` seconds. moreover, i will not worry about time taken, when I have defined explicit wait on an element.